# Linking fails for GetSaveFileName when cross compiling with MinGW

Tags: mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile a modified version of [UniLogger](https://eldeeb.net/wrdprs/?page_id=229) on Ubuntu 18.04 using mingw.  I'm getting the following link error:

`undefined reference to '_imp__GetSaveFileNameW@4'`

I found [this post on the MinGW mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/34523082/) saying one needs to explicitly link to comdlg32 so I tried that also:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -municode -o unilogger.exe -lcomdlg32 Source.cpp`

But still got the same error, as did the person asking in the post.  He and I both verified the presence of the function in the lib file:

`nm /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcomdlg32.a`

```
libcomdlg32s00012.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 T _GetSaveFileNameW@4
         U __head_lib32_libcomdlg32_a
00000000 i .idata$4
00000000 i .idata$5
00000000 i .idata$6
00000000 i .idata$7
00000000 I __imp__GetSaveFileNameW@4
00000000 t .text

libcomdlg32s00011.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 T _GetSaveFileNameA@4
         U __head_lib32_libcomdlg32_a
00000000 i .idata$4
00000000 i .idata$5
00000000 i .idata$6
00000000 i .idata$7
00000000 I __imp__GetSaveFileNameA@4
00000000 t .text
```

I'm at a bit of a loss at this point.

Comment: ...and the relevant answer is [Your linkage consumes libraries before the object files that refer to them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305704/1362568)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured out what the problem was - order of arguements on the command line:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -lcomdlg32 -municode -o unilogger.exe`

gives the link error, however

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -municode -o unilogger.exe -lcomdlg32`

Compiles just fine.  Actually think I've run into this problem before with gcc now that I think of it...